# Do foreign REITs distribute section 199a dividends?

Tags: united-states, taxes, reit

Do REIT ETFs that exclusively invest in foreign real estate distribute dividends that qualify for the section 199a deduction?

Also, do they pass on any foreign tax paid for deductions?

And finally, in the name of teaching a man to fish - I can go to any number of websites on any number of REITs. They'll tell you about dividend amounts and frequencies but they don't mention this sort of stuff that shows up on the 1099-DIV. Is there a way to get information on these tax characteristics on distributions for ETFs?